# Dateboosting in search result from marklogic

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8, marklogic-9

I want to boost query to get the search result on the top page which are relevant to latest released date of the publish content.

Is there any parameters do I need to pass in search API to get the required result.

OR

Any separate queries I need to create to do the same.

Any idea or suggestion on this would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I think you can easily achive this by doing sorting only

Answer (score 4):

You want to add a range query on that date. To make dates closer to today score higher, make the query be date <= today's date and use `score-function=reciprocal`. You may also need to adjust the [slope-factor option](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/relevance#id_32386) to get the effect you want.

See [the Search Developer's Guide](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/relevance), especially the section on "[Including a Range or Geospatial Query in Scoring](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/relevance#id_51643)", for more information.